# Undocumented field - CUSTOMER added to Googler Groups Member Resource 'type'

Tags: google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-groups-api

Is this a recent change or has it always been there?  We noticed today that when a domain has the 'everyone in the company' option selected, the membership resource comes back with a type of 'CUSTOMER' instead of 'USER' or 'GROUP'

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members#resource

If this is recent, are there any other recent changes to the API that are not yet documented?  We really need to be able to crack the code on how to provide updates coming out for the APIs.

Thanks,
  David